# Greasemonkey (JavaScript) textarea question

Tags: javascript, textarea, greasemonkey

I have written a basic Greasemonkey script which passes an output out to a [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp), like this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = "\n" + "Note:" + "\n" + "\n" + output_string;
```

It works like a charm, if you change the value from the source, it will update the textarea. However, as soon as you write anything yourself inside the textarea and select a value, it will not overwrite what you written inside the textarea. And you need to refresh the page entirely to be able to use the function again. Why is that?

Comment: How do you handle events in your script? How do you reference the textarea? Please add more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `textarea`'s `value` attribute is set as soon as you type something into it. This overrides any `innerHTML` value.

You should be using the `value` attribute to set the contents of input elements like `textarea`.

Try this instead:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("comment").value = "\n" + "Note:" + "\n" + "\n" + output_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need your text area to always display the same text I suggest you attach blur event on it using your customized greasemonkey script. Blur event would do the same thing as it does now. The only change would be that `textarea` will be updated the moment cursor focuses off the `textarea`.

If that's what you were after, 'cause I didn't understand it quite clearly what are you trying to do.